# Помогите разобраться с замыканием в js

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Есть код, он выводит ошибку на второй строчке, почему?

```js
getBigName(userName);
function getBigName(name) {
 name = name + "";
 return name.toUpperCase();
}
let userName = 'Ivan';
```

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: userName is not defined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/variables#%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F) подробно описано и сказано, что сперва нужно объявить переменную, а потом в неё записывать данные..

```js
let userName = 'Ivan';
getBigName(userName);

function getBigName(name) {
  name = name + "";
  console.log(name);
  return name.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо Вам!

Comment: @Matc, Пожалуйста:)

Comment: @Matc,  слово `спасибо` всегда приятно, но можно и ответ принять...

Comment: Я в курсе, просто всплыло предупреждение, что ответ принять можно только через 7 минут)

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос не в замыкании, а во всплытии (`hoisting`)

В старой спецификации, переменные объявленные через `var` всплывали

```
console.log(foo) // undefined
var foo = 'foo'
```

Ошибки такой код не вызовет, потому что движок расценит его как:

```
var foo;
console.log(foo)
foo = 'foo'
```

Именованные функции по спецификации всплывают вместе с объявлением

```
foo() // foo
function foo() {
    console.log('foo')
}
```

В новой спецификации`es6` добавили два новых ключевых слова `let`, `const`, они тоже всплывают, но не так как мы ожидали

```
console.log(foo)
let foo = 'foo'
```

Движок прочитает это так

```
let foo
console.log(foo)
foo = 'foo'
```

Казалось бы, тоже самое что и с `var`, но есть один ньюанс, хоть `let` и всплывает, но использовать его **до** присвоения **нельзя**. Это называется [временная мертвая зона](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198849/what-is-the-temporal-dead-zone). Поэтому такой код выкидывает ошибку